# How can I tell how my DLL was loaded?

Tags: windows, delphi, dll

How can my DLL detect whether it was loaded implicitly or explicitly?

*Example MyTestDll.dll*

```
library MyTestDll;

uses SimpleShareMem, Windows, Dialogs;

procedure DetectMethodDllLoad: bool;
begin
  // ?????
  // need to detect loading method - implicit or explicit
end;

procedure MyTest; stdcall;
begin
  if DetectMethodDllLoad then
    ShowMessage('Working Program1 (implicit dll load)')
  else
    ShowMessage('Working Program2 (explicit dll load)');
end;

exports MyTest;

begin
end.
```

*Program1.exe (implicit dll load)*

```
procedure MyTest; stdcall; external 'MyTestDll.dll' Name 'MyTest';

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyTest;
end;
```

*Program2.exe (explicit dll load)*

```
type
  TMyTest = procedure; stdcall;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyTest: TMyTest;
  H: HModule;
begin
  H := LoadLibrary('MyTestDll.dll');
  if H = 0 then
    exit;
  @MyTest := GetProcAddress(H, 'MyTest');
  if Assigned(MyTest) then
    MyTest;
  FreeLibrary(H);
end;
```

How can I implement `DetectMethodDllLoad`?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: DLLs use dynamic linking rather than static linking. Perhaps the distinction you wish to draw is between implicit and explicit linking. No matter, there is no question here and I vote to close.

Comment: Well, now I will add an example

Comment: >> closed as not a real question :: Why this question "not real"???

Comment: the close votes racked up before you updated the question. I understand you now.

Comment: If a program loads *a.dll* explicitly with LoadLibrary, and *a.dll* loads *b.dll* implicitly, what should `DetectMethodDllLoad` return inside of *b.dll*?

Comment: You should normally be able to obtain that information by supplying a `DllMain` function to `DllProcEx` and examining the 'lpReserved' parameter when 'fdwReason' is DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH. But it seems, when the `begin` of the dll runs it's too late to assign to DllProcEx, the process is already attached. Hence the note in the docs: *DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH is passed to the procedure only if the DLL's initialization code calls the procedure and specifies DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH as a parameter.* Renders it pretty usesless I think.

Comment: @David - The question is not about linking it's about loading. I don't think there's anything wrong with *dynamic/static loading* of a dll terminology-wise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can create a DllMain procedure, the lpReserved parameter for the DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH call will tell you whether the load is static or dynamic.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682583%28VS.85%29.aspx

You could certainly do this in C.  I don't know whether it is possible in Delphi.

Comment: Yes, this that is necessary. But how it to make on Delphi? ;)

Comment: Assign a handler to the `SysInit.DllProcEx` callback in your DLL's `initialization` section. The problem, however, is that the `DllProc/Ex` callbacks are not called for `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` because they have not been assigned yet at that time. You could try processinging for the first  `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH`event though.

Comment: But @Remy, the thread-attach call doesn't define the `lpReserved` parameter. That's only set for process-attach.

Comment: The `SysInit.DllProc/Ex` callbacks are the only way Delphi exposes access to the `DllMain()` parameters, but `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` is triggered before the callbacks can be assigned in user code, and Delphi does not cache the `lpReserved` value anywhere, so you are out of luck in Delphi.  Switch to C++ :-)

Comment: You can use Delphi .pas files in a C++ project, but you cannot use C++ .c/.cpp files in a Delphi project. You would have to create a C++ project to solve this issue, as you cannot replace Delphi's default `DllMain()` handler with your own code like you can in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very good tutorial with the 2 methods, static and dynamic:

[Static vs. Dynamic Dynamic Link Library Loading - A Comparison](http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/delphi-dll-loading-static-dynamic.htm)

Comment: The correct terminology is implicit linking when the imports are included in the loading modules import table and explicit linking when LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress is used. Static linking is what you get with `$LINK`. You can call it static linking if you really want to, but that is not the official terminology.

Comment: If you wish to learn more about this topic see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/253b8k2c(VS.80).aspx

Comment: ok. thx for the terminology and your link. BTW, this is written like this in the [doc](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Libraries_and_Packages).

Comment: Also there is delay load without writing any LoadLibrary code.

Comment: @Warren: Yes, we can see it in the [doc's page](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Libraries_and_Packages) I put in a previous comment.

Comment: See 'DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH' in the documentation of [DllMain Entry Point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) where MS uses *"dynamic loading"* and *"static loading"* terms for DLLs.

Answer (score -1):

**Thanks Harry Johnston!!!** :)

```
library MyTestDll;  

uses SimpleShareMem, Windows, Dialogs;  

type
PDllEntryPointFrame = ^TDllEntryPointFrame;
TDllEntryPointFrame = packed record
hModule: THandle; // DLL module handle
dwReason: DWord; // reason for calling DLLEntryPoint function of DLL
bStatic: LongBool; // TRUE if DLL is loading/unloading satically, FALSE - dinamically
end;

function DetectMethodDllLoad: bool;  
asm
mov edx, [hInstance]
mov eax, ebp
@@nextframe:
cmp [eax + $08].TDllEntryPointFrame.hModule, edx
je @@found
mov eax, [eax]
jmp @@nextframe
@@found:
mov eax, [eax + $08].TDllEntryPointFrame.bStatic
end;

procedure MyTest; stdcall;  
begin  
...
end;  

exports MyTest;  

begin  
  if DetectMethodDllLoad then  
    ShowMessage('Working Program1 (implicit dll load)')  
  else  
    ShowMessage('Working Program2 (explicit dll load)');  
end.
```

P.s. System.TDLLProcEx **not working** in Delphi XE!

```
library MyTestDll; 

....

procedure MyDLLProcEx(Reason:integer;x:pointer);
begin
if x=nil then showmessage('dyn') else showmessage('stat');
end;

begin
DLLProcEx:=@MyDLLProcEx;
end;
```

x = nil always :(

Comment: -1 for several reasons: First, there's no explanation of what this code does (or why Harry Johnston has anything to do with it). Second, I happen to understand what that code is doing, and I cannot endorse spelunking in undocumented call-stack structures, at least not without some rationale for why we should expect it to be valid in any particular version of Delphi. Third, the code meant to demonstrate the correct answer doesn't work, by your own admission. This answer will harm or mislead the people who come here for an answer later.

Comment: @Gu: `DllProcEx` is not called automatically for `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH`, you have to call it manually after assigning `DllProcEx`.  Delphi does not expose access to the Reserved value of the `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` event.

Comment: @Rob, presumably Delphi can be trusted to use the standard Windows call stack, at least provisionally?  What I don't understand is why the call to DetectMethodDllLoad is happening from within the DllMain function in the first place, can someone clarify this?  With the restrictions on what you can do inside DllMain you would need to be very careful about using runtime library functions.

Comment: @Rob, I think Gu means that the second piece of code doesn't work, not that the first piece doesn't.

Comment: @Harry, *System.pas* and *SysInit.pas* do some funny things. They don't necessarily adhere to the usual calling conventions. The detection function is called from the DLL's entry point because that's the only place where the `lpReserved` parameter will be available. You can't call it from any exported function because then the entry-point parameters won't be on the stack anymore. Other RTL functions are fine; it's DLL functions you need to avoid. `DetectMethodDllLoad ` calls none. And maybe I should have said *accepted* instead of *correct*; I know the second code is what Gu was referring to.

Comment: @Rob, I understand that the detection function has to be called from the DLL's entry point in order to work.  However, I don't understand why the code provided results in the detection function being called from the DLL's entry point!  The last six lines of code appear to be an unnamed function, but surely unnamed functions don't automatically get run within DllMain?  (And are the calls to ShowMessage safe?)

Comment: @Harry, the begin-end block of the DPR file is the programmer-accessible entry point of the module, whether it's an EXE or a DLL. It's worked that way for decades. (The calls to ShowMessage aren't wise, but they're fine to illustrate the expected results of the function in example code.)

Comment: In a DLL project, a unit's entry point code gets called in the context of the `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` event of Delphi's `DllMain()` handler.  So the detach code is merely looking at the call stack that invokes the entry point code.

Comment: Thanks @Rob.  I think Gu's code is reasonably safe, at least for the case where the DLL is explicitly loaded, because the call stack needs to be intact for the benefit of the calling program.  (The call to DllMain actually takes place from inside the call to LoadLibrary.)  So while untested versions of Delphi might disrupt the call stack, they would be wrong (i.e., breaking standards) to do so.  One caveat: the code doesn't handle the case where the call stack is exhausted unsuccessfully, and it should.

Comment: @Harry, assumption No. 1 of the code is that the caller used EBP as the frame pointer, but EBP could really be anything. Assumption No. 2 is that the functions between here and DllMain used a calling convention where parameters are put on the stack from right to left; if that's not the case, then the value just below our return address might be anything, including a coincidental copy of HInstance. Assumption No. 3 is that the most recent function to have HInstance for its first parameter also had lpReserved for its third. DllMain isn't necessarily the most recent call like that.

Comment: @Rob, assumption #1 should be safe.  EBP has to be the frame pointer, or else exception handling (for example) won't work properly.  Points #2 and #3 are valid, but in the real world the risk of this happening is probably minimal.  I mean, I wouldn't want to use it for controlling a nuclear reactor, but otherwise ... yes, it would be better to use a lower-level language, or to restructure to avoid needing the information, but for many purposes this hack should be "good enough".

Comment: Exception handling has nothing to do with frame pointers, @Harry. Exception frames get stored in FS:[0]. Some exception handlers choose to extend the EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION structure with additional data that includes the frame pointer, so the exception handler has easier access to the local variables from the associated code, but if there is no exception handler in the current function, then EBP doesn't matter at all and can be used as just another general-purpose register.

Comment: @Rob, in Windows exception handling is done via the stack frames.   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679327%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Harry, exception-registration structures are put on the stack, but that doesn't make them stack frames. The article you link to has the terminology wrong. It's convenient to imagine the system searching back through each called function for a handler, but in fact the system searches through the linked list of exception registrations and calls each of the handlers until it finds one that handles the exception. That linked list starts at FS:[0], not EBP. The handlers needn't even live inside the function where the exception frame was created.